# Is it possible to develop iPhone applications on Mac without Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcodebuild

Is it possible to develop iPhone applications on Mac without Xcode?

Comment: but why? (@KennyTM: how can you just comment 'Yes'? I get hit by the minimum length requirement.)

Comment: @Thilo: Add lots of zero-width space (U+200B).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to at least install Xcode (or more specifically the Apple Developer Tools package, which includes Xcode and various other tools etc). You can then use the underlying tools directly without actually going via the Xcode IDE, but that would be a perverse thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, Xcode is just an IDE around command-line tools such as `make`, `gcc` and others. But Xcode makes a lot of things easy for you, building your own development environment would be a lot of work. If you just want to use a different editor, you might want to check out `man xcodebuild`.

Comment: “Without Xcode” can mean two things, not installing or not using. I assume he means “not using.”

Comment: Also, figuring out all the tools you need to invoke, the right order, correct command-line parameters, etc all would take quite some time.  But yes, it is certainly possible.

Comment: You can configure an external editor inside Xcode, so if you just want to use an external editor you can still rely on Xcode for its project/target configuration features.

Answer (score 1):

It's *possible* to not use Xcode, but trying to develop iPhone apps without it would make your life so much harder I'd *strongly* encourage you to use it. You'll have to install the dev tools that includes it anyway, and it's mandatory for deploying the app on the iPhone to test it so you may as well get using it now.